# About performance (memory or cpu)

Tags: java, performance

this question is about java coding, my question is easy so i'll explain it with a little example :)

I have a String array full of arguments, and i have to check it's length several times, so, it's better to save the amount of arguments (array length) in a variable, or just call the length every single time?, i suppose that storing a variable will consume more memory, and the other way will use more cpu, just want to ask what do you think is better thanks!

Example:

```
String[] arguments = {"a","b","c"};
int numberOfArguments = arguments.length;
if(numberOfArguments == 1)do whatever
if(numberOfArguments == 2)do whatever
if(numberOfArguments == 3)do whatever
```

etc

OR

```
String[] arguments = {"a","b","c"};
if(arguments.length == 1)do whatever
if(arguments.length == 2)do whatever
if(arguments.length == 3)do whatever
```

EDIT: i know the difference will be really small.. but i'm asking for a LONG PROCESS, think big, a million of "arguments.length", so for that case i think is better to sacrifice a ultra small amount of memory to store the variable which should be better for the cpu than checking the arguments lenght a million of times than checking a variable value which is always the same, what do you think?

Comment: What do you find when you check the byte code?

Comment: I doubt you'll notice much of a difference. Anyway, I agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels that you should compare the resulting byte code to check if there is any difference to start with after compilation. On a side note, how about a `switch..case`?

Comment: The difference in memory consumption and CPU load between both cases is so infinitesimal that you wouldn't notice it if you had your code running in a machine from the 80's.

Comment: *"have to check it's length several times"*  If that read *"several **100s of thousands of** times"* it might make sense.  As it is, it wreaks of 'premature optimization'.

Comment: Accessing the length of an array is quite cheap, and there is little benefit in "caching" the value, except possibly to make your code simpler.  And a String length is only very slightly more expensive to access.

Comment: If this were C, I would say cache the value in a separate variable with the register storage keyword.  Since this is Java, it is entirely possible that the compiler will optimize it out the same--you really have to look at the bytecode on this one.

Answer (score 4):

This is a premature optimization; do whatever you find more readable/easier to manage. Personally, I prefer to just refer to the `length` field directly because I see no point in storing it in another variable (unless, perhaps, the length of the array has a different meaning in the context of your program than simply a count of elements - in such a case it might be appropriate to store it in a reasonably named variable). In any case, you can rest assured that there will be no appreciable performance difference between the two.

By the way, `array.length` might even be *faster* in some cases (assuming you're able to see any time difference whatsoever) than storing the length in a local variable and using that instead. There's even a bytecode operand reserved specifically for this: `be` (`arraylength`), not to mention the optimizations that will be made along the way.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: you can't compare storage with speed, those are different things.
What you can do is determine how much you value each. If you need 100% speed, you will go for the speed option and vice versa.

Usually you want an equal consideration, which brings us to this:
it's up to your own preference. Will you often access that property? Maybe it's interesting to store it in a variable.

See for yourself what you find easier to use: your example has very little influence either way. Retrieving the size of a list is already stored in a variable so there's no looping going on.

Comment: It's not a comparation, i'm asking for your opinion, if you think is better to use memory OR cpu, not comparing both.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in both is creating one extra variable versus getting length of array, the difference will depend on how you are using this code.

If you create a millions instances of this class, then in first approach you will be creating million variable and you can now think of memory being used more in first approach.

Reading length of array is not expensive, so in nutshell it really depend on how is this code being used in your project.

Leaving everything aside, since length is being used multiple times creating a variable is a good practice.

Cheers !!

Answer (score -1):

Object oriented programming saves you having to do long if statements. Calculate the number of arguments once, and create an instance of the specific class for that scenario. Then you can call any method on that instance and it will act in a 'do whatever' manner for that situation.

(forgive my rusty Java...)

```
public interface Arguments{

   void foo();
}

public class OneArgument implements Arguments{


   public void foo(){
      // do whatever
   }
}

public class TwoArguments implements Arguments{


   public void foo(){
      // do whatever
   }
}

public class ThreeArguments implements Arguments{


   public void foo(){
      // do whatever
   }
}
```

Then you could have a factory method:

```
public static Arguments create(String[] args){

   if(args.length == 1) return new OneArgument();
   else if(args.length == 2) return new TwoArguments();
   else if(args.length == 3) return new ThreeArguments();
   else throw new Exception();

}
```

Better thought out architecture will most likely yield better performance in the long run.